# Definition of the Besov space

Tags: functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, besov-space

The Besov spaces can be defined using the dyadic decomposition.  For this purpose,  let $\varphi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^n)$ be such
$ {\rm supp}(\varphi) \subseteq \left\{x; \,  \frac 12<  |x| < 2\right\}$ and denote
$$\varphi_j(x) = \varphi\left(2^{-j}x\right)\quad\text{for} \quad j\in \mathbb N^\ast\quad \text{and}\quad \varphi_0 = 1-\sum_{j=1}^\infty \varphi_j.$$

In this [paper](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN266833020_0145?tify=%7B%22view%22:%22info%22,%22pages%22:%5B257%5D%7D). For any  $1\leq p, q \leq \infty,$ the Besov space $B^0_{pq}$ is defined as the  closure of $C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^n)$ with respect to the norm $$\|u\|_{B_{pq}^0} := \left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty \left\| \mathfrak{F}^{-1} (\varphi_j \hat u)\right\|_p^q  \right)^{\frac 1q},$$
where $\mathfrak{F}^{-1}$ is the inverse Fourier transform. Can this definition be extended for $B^s_{pq}$ with $s\in \mathbb R,$ so that $B^s_{pq}$ is the
closure of $C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^n)$ with respect to the norm $$\|u\|_{B_{pq}^s} := \left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty 2^{jsq} \left\| \mathfrak{F}^{-1} (\varphi_j \hat u)\right\|_p^q  \right)^{\frac 1q}?$$

Or there is a condition on $s$? Thank you for any hint.

Comment: For $s>0$, yes, except not in the case $q=\infty$. See books by Hans Triebel on Function Spaces. For $s<0$, I would guess not. In any case, you can certainly define these spaces of tempered distributions with norms, but the question of whether or not this is the closure of $C_c^\infty$ w.r.t. these norms is another question.

Comment: In other words, $\|u\|_{B_{pq}^0}<0$ for any $u\in C_c^\infty.$ Which values of $s\neq 0$ do extend this property ?